# When to know if Python parallelism is enough?

Tags: python, c, multithreading, multiprocessing, xgboost

I know a little bit about the basics of Python parallelism (CPU-bound, use multiprocessing, IO-bound, use threads), but I am wondering what the best way to parallelize functions that spend almost all of their time in library code. My specific use case is parallelizing training thousands of XGBoost models. Importantly, I don't really care about parallelizing each model through the n_jobs parameter. Roughly,

```py
for col in col_list:
   train_xgboost(col, target)
```

I have tried using both multiprocessing and multithreading, roughly

```py
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
    pool.map(train_xgboost, col)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    pool.map(train_xgboost, col)
```

I see significant speedups with both, but I was wondering if parallelizing in a lower-level language would be useful at all given that pretty much all of train_xgboost is just calling C++ code. I know that there can be significant overhead associated with Python parallelism, but am unsure if those overheads apply in this case. Would re-writing my code to use the XGBoost C API and OpenMP do anything at all? I know sometimes the only way to find out is to benchmark, but unfortunately I barely know C and would love some guidance before I tried diving into a completely new language.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How much time does a single call of `train_xgboost` take?

Comment: Around 30 seconds

Comment: Overhead from Python parallelism is going to be on the order of milliseconds or less. There is not a lot you can save here. You doing it on CPU instead of CPU. That might speed things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know a little bit about the basics of Python parallelism (CPU-bound, use multiprocessing, IO-bound, use threads)

That's not a bad rule of thumb, but going a little deeper gets you a more predictive, though perhaps more difficult to evaluate rule:

- Needs the global interpreter lock to make progress: use multiprocessing
- Mostly does not need the GIL to make progress: use threads

IO-bound generally falls into the latter category.  CPU-bound falls into the former category *if the computation is (mostly) done in pure Python*, but probably falls into the latter category if the computation is mostly done in native code.

> I was wondering if parallelizing in a lower-level language would be useful at all given that pretty much all of train_xgboost is just calling C++ code.

Probably not.

> I know that there can be significant overhead associated with Python parallelism, but am unsure if those overheads apply in this case.

There is overhead associated with *all* parallel processing approaches.  But if your `train_xgboost()` just calls out, once, to native code, and waits for that call to return, then I don't see much room to trim overhead.  And that's in the "Mostly does not need the GIL to make progress" category, btw.  It might be different if the native code made frequent calls back into Python, or if there were a more complicated pattern of many calls to native code.

> Would re-writing my code to use the XGBoost C API and OpenMP do anything at all? I know sometimes the only way to find out is to benchmark,

It's hard to say whether that *could* provide a significant performance boost, but my guess would be that there's not much gain to be had.

In any case, this ...

> I barely know C

... provides good reason to suppose that any performance gain that might be available from this approach would be difficult for you, personally, to realize.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you have to pass a lot of data to your function calls, (I don't know about your `train_xgboost` function) it is better to avoid multiprocessing in Python. Python [serializes the arguments using pickle](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/faster-multiprocessing-pickle/#:%7E:text=Multiprocessing%20in%20Python&text=To%20enable%20this%2C%20when%20you,bytes%20are%20unserialized%20using%20pickle%20.), which might cause performance overhead. The processes will also not share any memory space, so you might also want to consider that (if you are thinking of sharing any kind of data between processes)

If you are going to use multithreading, you might want to consider a few more things:

- the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) will not allow parallel execution (unless it is released)
- the threads will not use multiple cores

That being said, both the techniques if used properly, will result in noticeable performance gain. However, as per my experience, compiled languages (C, C++ or Go) always perform better. Go also has an excellent concurrency model. But if the performance requirement is not an absolute bottleneck, you can go ahead with Python's concurrency implementation.